# pandas.read_csv leads to shifted column labels when dropping lines below header

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a .csv file with pandas, with a header looking like this:

```
System Information_1
System Information_2
System Information_3
System Information_4

"Label1"; "Label2"; "Label3"; "Label4"; "Label5"; "Label6"
"alternative Label1"; "alternative Label2"; "alternative Label3"; "alternative Label4"; "alternative Label5"; "alternative Label6"
"unit1"; "unit2"; "unit3"; "unit4"; "unit5"; "unit6"
```

I'm using the following code to read it:
`df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', header=5, skiprows=[6,7], encoding='latin1')`

My dataframe does however end up having `"unit1", "unit2", "unit3", "unit4", "unit5", "unit6"` instead of `"Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5", "Label6"` as column labels.

In an older version of my csv-file, however, the import code works properly. The difference I could spot between the files was that the older file has a full set of separators in the first 4 rows:

```
System Information_1;;;;;
System Information_2;;;;; 
etc.
```

Does anyone know where that error comes from and how to solve it?

Comment: please format your question's description properly

Comment: what do you mean by "properly"? sorry, I'm new here

Comment: --> run "edit" mode --> use "Markdown editing panel" --> surround your code blocks with a proper edit items (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Judith, Welcome to the SO , However , it  worths to add  the details How your raw data looks like , if you have a Dataframe , you can post few Lines of that and the desired output you want from the data.  Will you be able to post the CSV file somewhere over  the Internet.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest You can edit the formatting yourself (I've done it now).

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the first rows, too, but then also don't set header to `5`, because it's 0 then, so you can leave it to be detected automatically :

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=';', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,6,7], encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list as your header argument:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """System Information_1
System Information_2
System Information_3
System Information_4

"Label1"; "Label2"; "Label3"; "Label4"; "Label5"; "Label6"
"alternative Label1"; "alternative Label2"; "alternative Label3" "alternative Label4"; "alternative Label5"; "alternative Label6"
"unit1"; "unit2"; "unit3"; "unit4"; "unit5"; "unit6" 
1;2;3;4;5;6
10;20;30;40;50;60
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';', header=[4], skiprows=[6, 7], encoding='latin1')
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: The answer from @SpghttCd works perfectly well too. They got here quicker than I did!

Answer (score 0):

The "header" parameter starts counting after the "skiprows" parameter.

If you want to use the label as header:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pruebasof.csv', sep=';', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,6], encoding='latin1')
```

Otherwhise, if you want to use the alternative label as header:

```
df = pd.read_csv('pruebasof.csv', sep=';', skiprows=6, encoding='latin1')
```

I made it so you can use the label while keeping the "units" as data for the labels.